# What are the drawbacks of deploying a website using the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web, web-deployment

I started my journey into web applications about three years ago and I'm happy to say that I've finally deployed a working website. My concern is that to deploy the website I use the Eclipse IDE and a Tomcat webserver. So basically I right click the project in Eclipse and then choose "Run As > Run on Server" and then select the Tomcat server I downloaded - from that point on the console spits out some startup messages and my website is online and ready for use. What are are some of the drawbacks of deploying a project this way. I've read just briefly about WAR files and adding them to Tomcats Webapps folder but I could neither get that working nor did I understand completely the process...so is it acceptable to just deploy the project the way I have been doing thus far by running it in Eclipse?

Comment: Isn't that just running the application on your computer where Eclipse is running?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be? Although if you want to deploy your application somewhere *else* it might be a good idea to understand other mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Development machine and deployment server is different.
On Deployment server one may not have eclipse always.

WAR file is just a webarchive which includes all the necessary files. WAR makes your project portable.

Export WAR from eclipse place it in tomcat webapps in any machine and restart tomcat.

You should have your webapp successfully running on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

That's a fine way for deploying a server when you're learning, or always have the server (the only server!) running on your development machine.

If you need to push to a remote machine, it won't work, and you'll need to learn other methods then, but for now, what you're doing is fine.